# NSwag: a clear steps and clean sample on how to use class extensions in NSwag studio

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, nswag, nswagstudio

There are not clear documentation on how to extend the auto-generated TS file using NSwag. I mean the extension methods with a protector access modifier

here a discussion with the NSwag's owner:

https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1012

but there is some uncertainty among the steps followed. especially in the case when adding a static suffix and/or prefix to the controller's name.

Can someone provide a clear explanation of how can we extend the auto-generated methods?

Comment: The docs are here: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/TypeScriptGenerator#extended-classes-and-extension-code and here: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/TypeScriptClientGenerator#extended-classes-and-extension-code

Comment: Thank you for your pass, I have found that classes who have a prefix and/or suffix to the will not follow the same convention as it is in the documentation, please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the correct convention to extend the auto-generated classes with prefixes and/or suffixes is to follow the rule as below

```
  { prefixIfExists} + {classname} + {suffixIfExists} extends generated.{classnameOnly} {

}
```

Example:

[image]

```
class FilesApplicationsManagerService extends generated.FilesApplicationsManager {
}
```